# Stamp duty first time buyer renting after 6 months

Tags: united-kingdom, mortgage, rental-property, first-time-home-buyer

I'm looking to buy my first house, but I'm only planning on living in it for 6 months or so before going cycle touring next summer (covide dependant..!). I'd like to rent it out for 6-12 months after that, then move back in.

My questions are:

1. Would I have to back pay the first time buyer stamp duty exemption
2. How easy would it be to change my mortgage to a buy to let after six months

Any help is greatly appreciated, I've searched online and can't find any information about this specific situation.

Edit: This is for a property in England (sheffield) the transaction would not be completed before March

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Please add a country tag.  If the US, also add a state tag.

Comment: As this is United Kingdom, please state if this is England, Wales, Scotland or Northern Ireland, and if the transaction will complete by the end of March.

Comment: #2 will depend on the specific terms of your lender and the mortgage

Comment: A residential mortgage typically requires a minimum deposit of 10% (maybe even slightly higher given current circumstances) whereas a buy-to-let mortgage typically requires a minimum deposit of 25% so you would have to make up the difference in those 6-12 months assuming you put 10% down initially.

Comment: Thanks Jsk, I'd just about be able to stretch to a 25% deposit